# Vlookup when lookup cell has string

Tags: excel

Trying to figure this out

Say cell A1 has unique values "Car | Bike | Truck ", I would like to use Vlookup to match this to a table that has values for one of the unique values

```
Category    Value
Shoes       1
Bike        2
Hat         3
Coat        4
```

Example above would return 2

There could be instances where the values dont exist in the table, which is OK. Also, I can change " | " to commas if needed, it's just how the output file currently is.

Thanks!

Comment: See [If a particular word exists within a field then assign corresponding value from a table“legend”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752496/if-a-particular-word-exists-within-a-field-then-assign-corresponding-value-from/42753832#42753832), a virtual duplicate of your question that was asked a couple of days ago.

Comment: Assuming the `Categories` are in C2:C5 and the `Values` are in D2:D5, you can use this formula to return the value `2`: `=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$5,MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$C$2:$C$5&"*"),),0)),"No Matches")`

Comment: And what if there are two matches?  Will that ever happen?

Comment: Usually not, for a little context the values are actually promotions so this formula is helping me parse out pre-promotion offers vs. promotion offers. The table it's referencing is promotion only so there shouldnt ever be two promotions in one cell

Comment: @tigeravatar The formula worked!! For my own knowledge can you explain the second part of the formula? Specifically "MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$C$2:$‌​C$5&"*"),),0))" I'm not following how that's working exactly;.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the *Array Formula*:

```
=INDEX(D2:D5,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2:C5,A1)),0))
```

With data like:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.